# Understanding bundler dependency resolution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I am migrating an application from Rails 4 to Rails 5 but am struggling to get a complete bundle due to dependency conflicts.  I am a bit confused as to why this is a problem as I don't completely understand why the bundler cannot resolve the dependencies.

In this case, I am on Windows. I have installed Ruby 2.5.5 using BitNami Ruby and installed Rails 5.2.3. I deleted Gemfile.lock and ran bundle install.  The Gemfile specifies Ruby 2.5.5 and Rails 5.2.3.  No other gems have version requirements specified. Bundle is at 1.17.3.

My interest on this issue, other converting this particular application, is to better understand how bundle resolves dependencies. Looking at the bundler documentation, I haven't discovered the reason for some conflicts.  As an example, why would the bundler not accept actionpack 5.2.3 in this case:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    jquery-datatables-rails x64-mingw32 was resolved to 3.4.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.1) x64-mingw32

    rails (= 5.2.3) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.2.3) x64-mingw32

    rspec-rails x64-mingw32 was resolved to 3.8.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0) x64-mingw32

    simple_form x64-mingw32 was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 5.0) x64-mingw32

    rails (= 5.2.3) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 3.2.1, which
depends on
        actionpack (>= 4.0) x64-mingw32
```

Getting an understanding of this particular case would really help me.  I'd appreciate your assistance.

Gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.5.5' 
gem 'rails', '5.2.3'
gem 'aasm'
gem 'active_model-errors_details'
gem 'acts_as_tenant'
gem 'acts_as_xlsx'
gem 'addressable'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'awesome_print'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'aws-sdk-core'
gem 'aws-sdk-resources'
gem 'axlsx'
gem 'axlsx_rails'
gem 'better_delayed_job_web'
gem 'bindex'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'exception_notification-rake'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'ffi'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'forgery'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'json_pure'
gem 'logging'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'paloma'
gem 'pg'
gem 'phony'
gem 'phony_rails'
gem 'rake'
gem 'redis'
gem 'responders'
gem 'robocop'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'roo'
gem 'roo-xls'
gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'sass'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'smarter_csv'
gem 'sorcery'
gem 'spreadsheet'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'tzinfo-data'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'will_paginate'
group :production, :staging do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  platforms :ruby do
    gem 'unicorn'
  end
end
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'brakeman'
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'coffee-rails-source-maps'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'require_reloader'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'web-console'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem "faker"
  gem "squasher"
  gem 'fabrication'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'method_source'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-collection_matchers'
  gem 'rspec-core'
  gem 'rspec-expectations'
  gem 'rspec-mocks'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rspec-support'
  gem 'thin'
end
group :test do
  gem "launchy"
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'json_spec'
  gem 'mocha'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'shoulda-callback-matchers'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end
```

Comment: can you include your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` file?

Comment: @Hardik Well, the Gemfile.lock was deleted.  Because this app is being ported from Rails 4 to 5, the lock meant pretty much nothing.  I will post the Gemfile, but my question isn't really about it.  It is more about understanding Bundler's decision making.  In regards to the direct question above, in this particular case, why would the Bundler not just accept ActionPack 5.2.3?  What is preventing that?  Thanks.

Comment: The error you added doesn't seem to prevent `bundler` from resolving the dependencies, but is it the full error or there's more lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you look at the complete output from your `bundle install` it is pretty long:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    jquery-datatables-rails was resolved to 3.4.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.1)

    rails (= 5.2.3) was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)

    rspec-rails was resolved to 3.8.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0)

    simple_form was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 5.0)

    rails (= 5.2.3) was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0) was resolved to 3.2.1, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 4.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.2.3) was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.2.3)

    web-console was resolved to 4.0.1, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    acts_as_xlsx was resolved to 1.0.6, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 2.3.9)

    better_delayed_job_web was resolved to 1.3.12, which depends on
      activerecord (> 3.0.0)

    delayed_job_active_record was resolved to 4.1.4, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 6.1)

    rails (= 5.2.3) was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
      activerecord (= 5.2.3)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    active_model-errors_details was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
      activesupport

    delayed_job was resolved to 4.1.8, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 6.1)

    exception_notification-rake was resolved to 0.3.0, which depends on
      exception_notification (~> 4.2.0) was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
        activesupport (>= 4.0, < 6)

    rails (= 5.2.3) was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)

    rspec-rails was resolved to 3.8.2, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.0)

    shoulda-matchers was resolved to 4.1.2, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

    rails (= 5.2.3) was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0) was resolved to 3.2.1, which depends on
        activesupport (>= 4.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "axlsx":
  In Gemfile:
    axlsx

    acts_as_xlsx was resolved to 1.0.6, which depends on
      axlsx (>= 1.0.13)

    axlsx_rails was resolved to 0.5.2, which depends on
      axlsx (>= 2.0.1)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "exception_notification":
  In Gemfile:
    exception_notification

    exception_notification-rake was resolved to 0.3.0, which depends on
      exception_notification (~> 4.2.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.2.3)

    acts_as_tenant was resolved to 0.4.4, which depends on
      rails (>= 4.0)

    axlsx_rails was resolved to 0.1.5, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.1)
```

Maybe too long, and there is a lot of noise in the output. But if you try to dig through you will find some interesting lines:

```
    web-console was resolved to 4.0.1, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
```

this means that `web-console` v4.0.1 needs at least `activemodel` gem 6.0.0, so you should limit `web-console` to valid version for rails 5, which is [3.7.0](https://rubygems.org/gems/web-console/versions/3.7.0), version in your gemfile:

```
  gem web-console, '< 4.0'
```

now when you try to run `bundle install` again it will show you similar errors again but there will be some differences. In new output you will find following difference:

```
    active_model-errors_details was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.0, < 5.0.0.alpha)
```

This means that `active_model-errro_details` cannot be run with Rails 5. According to Rubygems, this gem cannot be run with Rails 5.2.3 see https://rubygems.org/gems/active_model-errors_details, so I commented it out in gemfile:

```
# gem 'active_model-errors_details'
```

and tried to run `bundle install` again. There are still some compatibility errors with gem versions this time it is `quiet_assets` gem:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    quiet_assets was resolved to 1.0.1, which depends on
      railties (~> 3.1)
```

You can see it dependes on Rails 3.x. If you look at the rubygems, you will see that even the latest version of `quiet_assets` cannot be run with Rails 5. Again I removed the gem from the Gemfile:

```
 # gem 'quiet_assets'
```

Now when you try to run `bundle install` all of the gems version problems will be solved and gems will be successfully installed.

It is a bit messy and there is a lot of noise in the error output, but if you read it carefully, you will find what is wrong.

Comment: Good answer. You _ought_ not to have to manually limit `web-console`, bundler should have been able to figure out the version that works with the version of Rails you specified. But sometimes bundler fails, or sometimes you need to do this to make the *real* error clear in the messages (as edariedl did). But once you fixed the real error with `quiet_assets`, you could try removing the restriction on `web-console` -- bundler will probably work fine without the explicit restriction, now that `quiet_assets` is gone.

Comment: @edariedl I appreciate the work and it certainly does work.  Great explanation, too.  And, I will use your answer and accept it for the bounty.  However, I don't yet understand Bundler's decision making well enough to do it myself next time.  I go back to my original question.  Why  did Bundler not resolve ActionPack to 5.2.3?

Comment: @Richard_G I also think that ActionPack 5.2.3 should be resolved. There is nothing wrong with it. In general I take it as a noise. You have to go through the error log and find the lines where there is a version mismatch between required gems (examples of these mismatches are in my answer above), and fix these problems one by one in your Gemfile (version constraints, remove some gems, etc.) until everything is correctly resolved.

Comment: @jrochkind great point, you are totally right. When you fix all the important problems, and everything is correctly resolved, you can remove `web-console` version constraint and it will work just fine.

Comment: @Richard_G also don't forget that when you fix one problem some new ones can show up, it happened to me with your Gemfile. When I fixed one problem and run `bundle install` new problem showed up with some other gem which was not in the error output before.

Comment: @edariedl I followed  your recommendations and bundler worked fine.  I also removed the web-console restriction in the end and it caused no problem.  Now, I am in the mode of resolving code inconsistencies.  For example, gem axlsx does not play well with rubyzip 1.2.3 even though it doesn't provide a restriction in the gemspec.  This is what I expected would happen so, moving on.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: "Why did Bundler not resolve ActionPack to 5.2.3?"  I think Bundler _did_ resolve ActionPack to 5.2.3? The real problem here is not the resolution, but that it didn't give you a very good explanation of _why_ a consistent dependency tree couldn't be found. There are of course an infinite number of things that _could_ be changed to result in a resolvable tree, from removing one or more gems (just remove Rails! :)) to changing the version requirements on one or more gems.  It's a hard problem to come up with the one a human is likely to consider 'right', and bundler isn't always great at it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to update your bundle by running "bundle update" than run bundle install

Comment: Tried both.  Neither helped.  Still need to understand the point of the question.  Why does Bundler make these decisions.  I do not understand why, in this particular case, Bundler does not simply accept ActionPack 5.2.3  What restriction prevents that.

Comment: Bundler hold gem version and their dependencies and whenever we do the bundle install, rails will install only those gems which was never installed before. If any gem which were installed before and we removed from gemfile and again trying to install than bundler will just use that gem and lock that gem and its dependencies in side gemfile.lock. Each bundler support some specific version of rails / action pack etc.

Comment: There is no gemfile.lock, or wasn't until edariedl explained it.  Thanks.